# UITableView section clicked in Viewforheaderinsection

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a created custom `UIButton` in `UITableView` `viewForHeaderInSection`. Now when i click on the button within the section how will i know which section is clicked? Please help.

Comment: Is the button static or dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you add button in `viewForHeaderInSection` , just set tag with section number like bellow.,..

```
button.tag = section;
```

and when your button clicked at that time you can get that number with bellow code...

```
- (IBAction)yourButton_Clicked:(id) sender  
{
    NSLog(@"Section Number => %d",[sender tag]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIbutton *btn =[[UIButton alloc]init];
btn.tag=section;// this tag property will differentiate button for different section
}
```

by this you can access btn and add event on that burron

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIbutton *button =[[UIButton alloc]init];
    button.tag=section;// this tag property will differentiate button for different section
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In didselectrowatindexpath check for if(index path.section) is equal to the section you want the action.

Comment: OP was talking about a custom UIButton within the table cell, not the table cell itself

Comment: You can check for the section and in that you can vary the cell..Just try before commenting bro..

Comment: each section has a UIButton and when i click on the button i need to know which section is clicked so that i can expand rows only of that section